# Обмен данными PHP сайта и 1C

Tags: php, 1с

Есть документация представленная на сайте http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/.
Делаю первый шаг. Создал файл как написано в документации: http://<сайт>/<путь> /1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth.
В ответ сделал так:

```
echo 'success\n' . 'Название_куки\n' . 'Значение_куки';
```

При проверке подключения в 1С пишет "Соединение с сайтом не установлено.". Есть подозрение, что проблема в разделителе, возможно не правильно формирую ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как должно быть с двойными кавычками `"` иначе `\n` работать не будет.
Попробуйте:
`echo "success\n" . "Название_куки\n" . "Значение_куки\n";`